# Should I use 'meet' or 'meet with'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, technical

I'm not sure whether I should use 'meet' or 'meet with':

> - if a Python implementation meets our performance requirements, then...
> - if a Python implementation meets with our performance requirements, then...

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

The [definition of *meet*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meet) in this context is *fulfil* or *satisfy*, so to append *with* is redundant, and it should be omitted from formal or semi-formal writing.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about [meet(ing) the requirements](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meet-the-requirements) ([see also](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/meet+the+requirements)). None of those references list a possibility to include ''with''.

Answer (score -2):

In this context, either.  It doesn't really matter for the sake of a software analysis, and I think they might mean the same anyway.

The difference between "meets" and "meets with", generally, is that "meets" *usually* means *"meets for the first time"*, while "meets with" simply means "has a meeting with", "joins", or "encounters".  See sense #27 here http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meet--with

Both "meets" and "meets with" have also come to be used with *requirements*, to mean "satisfies", and that's the sense you're asking about.  So, either.